# Relativizations/Oracles for the BPP and RP complexity classes

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, complexity-classes, oracle-machines, probabilistic-turing-machines

If we consider the complexity classes **RP** and **BPP**, then to show **RP<sup>BPP</sup> = BPP<sup>RP</sup>** my first thought is we need to use some kind of majority voting to amplify our success probabilities. The issue is I don't necessarily see how we can get from a two sided error to a one sided error. How would I proceed to do that?